# How do I calculate how much power a servo consumes for specific degrees of turns?

Tags: servo

I have an FS5103B servo with a stall current of 780mA at 4.8V. So say I am calculating power for the stall current as P=UI^2, I get 2.92W. What does that mean, like is it for a one-degree turn or does it depend on how fast it did the turn? And also how do I go about calculating how much power it consumes for a specific degree of turn.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "Stall current" = "isn't moving."  There is no rotation when stalled.  Power will depend on the load, not the number of degrees of rotation.

Comment: Oh, I thought stall current means the current consumed by the servo when it is applying maximum torque, in my case 3kg, is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes.  The servo applies maximum torque when it is stalled - it just doesn't move.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I measured the current with a multimeter when turning the servo and it landed on 200mA. In that case the servos consumption is 0.2W. I am still wondering about what that means, and how the power for a one degree turn for example can be calculated.

Comment: You can't calculate power for a turn of 1 degree.  Power is instantaneous, but  a turn takes time.  You can measure the peak power during a turn, or the average power during a turn, but you can't say "2 watts for one degree."  What you have to do is to measure energy.  That's  power*time.

Comment: I see. So since I know that for a one-degree turn I send my servo a 0.61ms pulse am I calculating this correctly? 0.2*0.00061 = 0.000122Ws = 0.4392Wh ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123799/discussion-between-noname197-and-jre).

Comment: P=VI or UI in EU ;) = 3.744W ...x 0.61ms = 2.3 mJ per deg. which depends on load.

Comment: But servo power is not linear and continuous. A certain amount of current is required to start it moving, which also depends on the attached mass.  Then current declines as it accelerates.  And stopping can actually generate current (which is usually dumped or ignored.)  So less energy for one movement of 5 degrees, as opposed to 5 movements of 1 degree.  This sounds like a candidate for experimentation.

Comment: Power depends on acceleration current and braking current for small moves. Using an integral product of the waves. It is the sum of heat and work done for energy in mJ or power x time. Heat loss might be ~10%. Your biggest concern is the largest seek angle with inertia and load drawing the max current in a surge that decays as it speeds up with BEMF. Then repeats as it slows down.

Comment: Torque is proportional to current, V with velocity

Comment: Oh of course P=UI haha, my mistake. Thank you for all the answers.